# What to use for ORM?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, orm

I am planning of making a Node.JS express app. It will have MYSQL as database.
I am new to ORM's, Previously I used to write queries directly. 
And I am planning to make a commercial use of this app.
**Should I use ORM?? If yes which is better option?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORM's can simplify your data access code and eliminate the need to write SQL directly for certain types of typical database operations. If you foresee needing a lot of data access code of the type that ORM's handle, then yes, it's a good idea to use one.

Take a look here for some more info specifically for node.js: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-comparison-of-the-top-orms-for-2018-19c4feeaa5f